# ruby - trying to install nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I am trying to practice ruby. When I try to install nokogiri I am getting this error. I am following a tutorial.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161001-91233-6vj1dy.rb extconf.rb
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
  CC       entities.lo
  CC       encoding.lo
encoding.c:491:26: error: cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Werror,-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:573:27: error: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Werror,-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:729:26: error: cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Werror,-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: error: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Werror,-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [encoding.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/libxml2-2.9.4'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/libxml2-2.9.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --enable-static
        --disable-static
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --enable-cross-build
        --disable-cross-build
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
        from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
        from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
        from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
        from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:555:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

What is wrong? Any help is appreciated. I tried to search for solutions but no solution worked for me.

EDIT: I am using ubuntu 14.04 with RVM. What are the necessary libraries and headers for nokogiri?

Comment: Have you tried Ruby 2.3.1? Sometimes there's bug fixes for stuff like that.

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: There's an issue with libxml here, not Nokogiri per-se, so it's a dependency problem. Do you have any other versions of Ruby you can use? Does the non-RVM one work?

Comment: I have 2.2.4 I installed it just now. Is there anything I need to install?

Comment: The error relates to Ruby 2.3.0 or 2.3.1 as managed by RVM.

Answer (score 2):

As gem itself documentation:
[Installing Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

If you have issues, first make sure you have all the tooling necessary to compile C extensions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch
```

and then may be needed this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

And as you are on RVM try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

They install

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: I am getting extconf failed.